# Problem about this definite integral

Tags: integration

The indefinite integral of $$\int\ \sqrt{r^2+h^2}dh $$is 
$$\frac{1}{2}\big(h\sqrt{r^2+h^2}+r^2\ln(\sqrt{r^2+h^2}+r) \big)+c$$

The problem is for doing a physics problem, I have to calculate the definite integral in which limit for variable $h$ is $0$ to $H$. That's good. But I don't know what to do for variable $r$. I know at $h=H$, $r=0$; $h=0$, $r=R$. Would it be legitimate to use this limits for variable $r$?

P.S. I don't know much about multivarial calculus

Comment: You could also put $h=r sh(t)$ and use $1+sh^2t=ch^2t$.

Answer (score 2):

Substitute $\text{h}=\text{r}\tan(u)$ and $\text{d}\text{h}=r\sec^2(u)\space\text{d}u$:
$$\mathcal{I}\left(\text{h},\text{r}\right)=\int\sqrt{\text{h}^2+\text{r}^2}\space\text{d}\text{h}=\text{r}^2\int\sec^3(u)\space\text{d}u=\frac{\text{r}^2}{2}\left\{\tan(u)\sec(u)+\int\sec(u)\space\text{d}u\right\}$$

And:

$$\int\sec(u)\space\text{d}u=\ln\left|\tan(u)+\sec(u)\right|+\text{C}$$

Using the reduction formula:

$$\int\sec^\text{n}(u)\space\text{d}u=\frac{\sin(u)\sec^{\text{n}-1}(u)}{\text{n}-1}+\frac{\text{n}-2}{\text{n}-1}\int\sec^{\text{n}-2}(u)\space\text{d}u$$

---

When we use the definite integral:

$$\mathcal{I}\left(\text{H},\text{r}\right)=\int_0^\text{H}\sqrt{\text{h}^2+\text{r}^2}\space\text{d}\text{h}=\frac{\text{r}^2}{2}\cdot\left[\tan(u)\sec(u)+\ln\left|\tan(u)+\sec(u)\right|\right]_0^{\arctan\left(\frac{\text{H}}{\text{r}}\right)}$$

Now:

1. When $u=0$:
   $$\tan(0)\sec(0)+\ln\left|\tan(0)+\sec(0)\right|=0$$
2. When $u=\arctan\left(\frac{\text{H}}{\text{r}}\right)$:
   $$\tan(u)\sec(u)+\ln\left|\tan(u)+\sec(u)\right|=\frac{\text{H}\sqrt{1+\frac{\text{H}^2}{\text{r}^2}}}{\text{r}}+\ln\left|\frac{\text{H}}{\text{r}}+\sqrt{1+\frac{\text{H}^2}{\text{r}^2}}\right|$$

So:

$$\mathcal{I}\left(\text{H},\text{r}\right)=\frac{\text{r}^2}{2}\left\{\frac{\text{H}\sqrt{1+\frac{\text{H}^2}{\text{r}^2}}}{\text{r}}+\ln\left|\frac{\text{H}}{\text{r}}+\sqrt{1+\frac{\text{H}^2}{\text{r}^2}}\right|\right\}$$